# How to find out DLL path of a PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am using some cmdlets imported from a module and would like to find out where the DLLs are physically located so that I can use dotPeek or Reflector on them. Is there a way to find out the DLL path somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try with

```bsh
( get-command my-cmdlet ).dll
```

Comment: This even works with native cmdlets - `( get-command Rename-Item ).dll`. Of course you still have to do some digging to find the actual provider (e.g. `FileSystemProvider` in the GAC's `System.Management.Automation.dll`).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will work for cmdlets but not native functions such as `Add-BgpRouter` or `Add-PrinterDriver`. To determine the file path of a function use

```
$Function = Get-Command Add-BgpRouter
(Get-Module $Function.ModuleName).Path
```