# How to get Appx full name from a string with wildcard?

Tags: c, powershell, winapi, windows-store-apps, appx

In Powershell, this command `Get-AppxPackage *name*` can show a package full details. Is it possible to use any Windows API to get that equivalent result?

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32150759/8928481) and details of all [Package Query APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446597(v=vs.85).aspx). But they all need full package names or a running package process handle. Those don't work with wildcard string.

For example, if I installed this package `Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe` I can get details with `Get-AppxPackage *Calculator*` command. It is possible with any Windows API? I want to avoid `system()` or `CreateProcess()` sort of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could browse the app folder and grab the names from the xml manifest files. Admin rights are needed to get access to the app folder.

This example lists all apps with "xbox" in their name. The logic can be easily adapted to C# or another language.

```
$appNameFilter = '*xbox*'

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$appList = @()

$apps = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps' -Recurse -Filter 'AppxManifest.xml'

foreach( $app in $apps ) {

    $xml     = [xml](Get-Content $app.FullName)
    $appName = $xml.Package.Properties.DisplayName

    if( $appName -like $appNameFilter -and !$appList.Contains( $appName )) {
        $appList.Add( $appName )
    }
}

$appList
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @f6a4 answer. I took a reverse way to accomplish my goal. Here are my procedure:

I find an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16189406/8928481) to find the DLL behind `Get-AppxPacage` cmdlet in Powershell. With this command `(Get-Command Get-AppxPackage).dll`, Powershell shows the DLL file path as follows:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands\v4.0_10.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.dll
```

Go to that path in File Explorer and open `Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.dll` file in any .NET decompiler. Here I used [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy.git). The `Get-AppxManifest` command section has this C# code:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    AppxPackage appxPackage = this.packageManager.FindPackage(this.Package);
    if (appxPackage != null)
    {
        string str;
        if (appxPackage.IsBundle)
        {
            str = "\\AppxMetadata\\AppxBundleManifest.xml";
        }
        else
        {
            str = "\\AppxManifest.xml";
        }
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(appxPackage.InstallLocation + str, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream, new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore
            }))
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
                base.WriteObject(xmlDocument);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I converted that code a similar C code with Windows API. Here is the code snippet:

```
ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%ProgramFiles%\\WindowsApps", Buffer, MAX_PATH);

swprintf(FirstFile, MAX_PATH, L"%ls\\*", Buffer);

hFile = FindFirstFileW(FirstFile, &fileInfo);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
        if (wcsstr(fileInfo.cFileName, AppxName) != 0) {
            memcpy(PackageName, fileInfo.cFileName, MAX_PATH);
        }
    } while (FindNextFileW(hFile, &fileInfo) != 0);
}
```